# Format freemarker files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, freemarker

Actually we have freemarker files (ftl) under Eclipse + Freemarker plugin (from JBoss).

Do you know a way to format ftl files ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with format? syntax highlight? The JBoss plugin can do that.

Comment: syntax highlight is provided by jboss plugin but not formatting AFAIK

Comment: I have the same question to you now. I wonder why they don't create one, given freemarker file is just html file.

Comment: @HoangLong  - Freemarker can be used as a template language for much more than just HTML.  It could be SQL, dynamic text, anything really.

Comment: @AndyPryor: yeah, I know that. But I think it shouldn't be a problem. Freemarker compiler must be able to parse Freemarker code, so why not format it?

Comment: and it's very frustrated to edit not well-formatted nested freemarker code, you know

Comment: Totally agree, maybe we should write one? lol

Answer (score 16):

For ftl files that represent HTML configuring eclipse to open the HTML Editor works nicely. The HTML Editor has formatting capability as asked for. Todo configure eclipse to open ftl files with the HTML Editor you can use "open with" and there you'll get offered to link the HTML Editor permanently to the ftl extension:
[image: Dialog for Unsupported Content Type]

In the Content Types Preferences Page you can than actually add the *.ftl extension:
[image]

Comment: But is there a way to *change* the autoformat of the eclipse html editor? I think per default it does a crappy job

Comment: This does highlights the syntax in eclipse, but it validates same syntax against HTML validations, and it throws some warnings accordingly. But overall, it makes visibility and editing ftl files in eclipse editor much easily...!!

Answer (score 3):

I looked for a formatting tool a few months ago and I was unable to find any such tools.  To my knowledge there no such tools currently available, just the syntax highlighting you mentioned.

Comment: and it seems to me there is no tool for compile time check - you can only know the error as runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Associated the ftl file extension with your web page editor (assuming you have wtp already installed).

Answer (score 0):

An old question. I had the same problem for some time now, the default html editor contains some irritating features when working on freemarker templates, especially when using the bracket syntax.

Aptana studio eclipse plugin solves most of the problems:
http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download